# Detect Service Worker activation in front-end

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

Is there any possibility to detect the activation (not the installation!) of a new service worker in the front-end without using an interval method?

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straight-forward, if you take the time to get the basic ideas of the [ServiceWorkerContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer) and the [ServiceWorkerRegistration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration) interface.

The ServiceWorkerContainer fires a "controllerchange" event that can be listened to like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener(
    "controllerchange",
    (activationEvent)=>{
        var activatedSW = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
        //do anything with the activated service worker, e.g. opening a message channel to it, etc.
    }
);
```